# How to set up the css less in react native app

Tags: react-native, webpack, babeljs, less

I am looking for ways to integrate the custom less file with React Native project so that I can use all the pre-build custom classes from any specific design system.

I came across few projects but didn't want to use them due to the maintainability and reliability issues.

Kindly share with me any guidelines or documentation which have the required explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any. The problem is that there isn't always a react native style equivalent to css properties and additionally there can be major differences in how they applied. For instance,

- default flex direction is column, not row
- there is no grid layout
- text styles are not inherited from parents
- there is no display none
- lineHeight behaves differently

just from the top of my head. Even if you find a library that can convert your classes to native, you will have to rewrite a lot of the styling.